# I have trouble inserting all of the items from my SQL Server table to my SharePoint list

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, script-task, foreach-loop-container

I'm using an Execute SQL Task from where I get all the rows from my SQL Server table, and then I use a full result set to get all my data.

Then I go to  my ResultSet and I put my object variable that I name 0. After that I use a Foreach Loop Container, I put my object variable in the ADO enumerator. I Index my variable after, in my loop I put my script Task.

The Script Task is connected to SharePoint. in this script Task I insert the data from the data that I looked for it in my Execute SQL Task.

The problem is: in my SharePoint list I get only two rows from nine and I have a pop-up error in SSIS

The error is a

> DTS Script Task: Runtime Error

If it's not working it should not be working at all instead I have two rows inserted in SharePoint list.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Hi @champagneM12,
I suspect there could be a case of data mismatch or truncation. And one thing, if you are not providing the error details, it will not likely make it possible to solve your case.

Comment: I would like to add  a picture of my error but I'm not allowed to add pictures just yet. 
if you have an email or something I can send it to you.
The name of the error is : Runtime Error.
and the details of the error are :
 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo cultur

Comment: CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript() @Arthur

Comment: You must provide more details such as the script task code, a screenshot of the package control flow ...